# Can't access web app on Azure without hitting Microsoft Login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authorization

Feel like I'm missing something stupid here.

Have been publishing my web app from Visual Studio Web Express to Azure with no problems, and I can access the app via [peanutdynamite.azurewebsites.net](http://peanutdynamite.azurewebsites.net)

Problem is that I've been logged into my Microsoft account the whole time. Once I log out, I get redirected to the Microsoft Login page instead. I've also setup a custom domain but I'm still getting redirected to MS Login.

How do I get this app to be public facing?

Comment: Does the app do any kind of user authentication? There's a couple different ways to publish an app from VS, are you using the method with the web publish settings file?

Comment: It does perform user authentication. I'm using formsauthentication to a Users SQL table. Everything is in Users table...not using the default Accounts table which loaded as part of the MVC template. Also yes, im using the web publish settings file when I publish from VS.

Comment: Its almost like I've accidently told the app to use some form of MS authentication. BTW...my web config authentication is set to 'Forms'

Comment: Maybe Azure Active Directory somehow got into your mix. That would make an authentication process that looked like this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/waws/archive/2015/04/20/how-i-to-setup-azure-active-directory-with-a-web-app.aspx which is what I get when accessing your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try tossing this in the answers - when I check out the link, I get a bad request that says I need to be using Azure Active Directory and added as an external user. You may be trying to authenticate through Azure AD (on accident in addition to your forms solution). Check your Azure portal to see if you have the app and custom URL active in Azure AD.

Even if you don't, you might consider using Azure AD as your authentication process since you've already got an app with a custom URL; you could then skip the Forms auth. Found a post that elaborates a little on this error here w/ regard to being logged in or out of MS account and seeing the error https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/da762da9-949d-4b32-b88e-c9c370933c99/getting-aadsts50020-error-on-microsoft-login-page-when-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Comment: This is exactly what this issue is. I had somehow activated AD. Once I removed it, everything worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Amanda!

Comment: Just to help anyone else with the same issue.....first head down to your Active Directory in the Azure Portal and delete your web app from the AD. Then head back up to your web app and under Config remove AD from the Authentication / Authorization section. Finally restart your app.